# How do you save a large amount of data using SAGE?

Tags: matrix, save, command, sage

I'm trying to save a 'big' rational matrix in SAGE, but I'm running into problems. After computing my matrix A, which has size 5 x 10,000 and each entry contains rational numbers in fraction form with total number of digits for numerator and denominator more than 10 pages, I run the following command:

```
save(A, DATA + 'A').
```

This gives me the following error message:

```
Traceback(most recent call last): 
... 
RuntimeError: Segmentation fault.
```

I tried the same save command with a 'smaller' matrix and that worked fine. I should also note that I'm using a laptop with a 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor, Windows 8, i7 CPU @ 2.40 GHz and 8 GB RAM. I'm running SAGE on a virtual machine to which I allocated 5237 MB. Let me know if you need further information. My questions are:

1. Why can't I save my matrix? Why do I get the above error message? What does it mean?
2. How can I save my matrix A using this command? Is there any other way I can save it?

I have asked these same questions in another forum which specifically deals with SAGE, but I'm not getting an answer there. I have also spent a lot of time searching online about this question, but haven't seen anyone with this same problem.

Comment: "total number of digits... more than 10 pages" means around 75000 digits for the numerator and 75000 digits for the denominator.

Comment: Some quick number crunching reveals that you're trying to store at least 3.1 GB of data, not including the organizational structure etc. Could it be that you've just run your virtual machine out of memory? To test this, do two things: experiment and see if you can find where this error begins to occur (maybe try a 5 by 5000 matrix, then a 5 by 7500 matrix, and so on); then, allocate your machine some more memory, and see if this maximum increases.